# When/Where to create index in Google App Engine for Search API - Java

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

I'm creating a Java web server on the Google App Engine to do full text search on my database. Before I can search, I have to add all my database entries to an index. I should only have to do this once because the index is stored in persistent storage. Even if GCP creates a new instance of my Java server, the index should still be there.

My question is, how do I set up my program so it will only create the index once? I've tried using Warming Services, but as I understand it that will be called every time a new instance is created, so there'd be redundant calls to my index creation code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could totally decouple the search API index updates from the instance lifetime cycle by specifically tracking the index updates for each of the respective database (or datastore) entries.

Basically you'd only need to add a boolean property indicating if the entity was indexed (from the search API perspective, of course) or not. Then you'd only need to update the index with the entries for which the property is not set, which you can do at instance warm-up/startup or via periodic cron jobs, depending on your app needs.

Comment: Thanks for the update. I was hoping for a more elegant way of doing this, but I guess none exists.